# Write a program(java) to examine the matrix generated by the ortho method of the Transform3D class

Tags: java, methods, graphics, 3d

This is an exercise in a book called "Computer Graphics using java 2D and 3D" - year of the book is 2006.
I really have a big problem understanding what the question is.
If someone can just help me understand what i have to do, i have read most of the chapter but couldnt get it. 
The full question is: 
"8.7 - Write a program to examine the matrix generated by the ortho method of the Transform3D class. Allow users to enter the parameters for the method and print the resulting matrix."

Comment: Have you done 8.6? It is basically the same question, with the same answer except of using the `frustum` method you use the `ortho` method. So write a program, probably an applet, that will capture the 6 input values for the method and render it on the screen.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and your time. 
No i haven't done 8.6.
8.7 is an exercise that our teacher gave me to do. I asked him about details what i have to do and an explanation of my homework. But he couldnt explain what i should exactly do.
If you could give me a little more details about what output should be there in the screen when i enter the 6 input values to the ortho method. Sorry for asking too much.

Comment: The output should be a Matrix of 4x4 containing the results of the calling the `ortho` method.

Comment: Thanks alot, i get it now. Can you help me one more thing. About perspective method of class Transform3D. That is the 8.5 exercise. Same question just with different method.